# MySQL fulltext wrong records

Tags: sql, mysql

I have record like : TX-607383811_687144571

I am using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MATCH(mytable.FIELD) AGAINST('TX-607383811_687144571' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

However, I would like to search like this : 687144571 and find TX-607383811_687144571 without using like so I could not get any record with 687144571.

Also I tried this and etc..:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MATCH(mytable.FIELD) AGAINST('+687144571' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Not sure here, but have you tried BOOLEAN mode instead of NATURAL LANGUAGE mode? It appears that you can use an asterisk operator (*). Here's the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: I tried but doesn't worked for me. @Ben

Comment: Can you also post that query?

Comment: yes i tried which you send @Ben

Comment: that is  not possible use LIKE, * only work as placeholder for endings not beginnings

Comment: @Barmar the manual clearly indicates that * in full text searches is a place holder for endings only,  there is no way to find a match with only the ending, with match. a switch to elasticsearch is my recommendation if like is too slow

Comment: @Barmar the question is about Full TEXT INDEXEs not LIKE